# SerializationException Error reading JSON file in Android Studio for LibGDX uiskin

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, libgdx

I am trying to load a uiskin.json file to use for my application skin in LibGDX using Android Studio 2.3.3. However, when I try to load my skin I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: UI/uiskin.json
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:98)
at com.mathsvszombies2.game.Screens.HomeScreen.show(HomeScreen.java:66)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
at com.mathsvszombies2.game.Screens.StartScreen.render(StartScreen.java:58)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.mathsvszombies2.game.MathsVsZombies.render(MathsVsZombies.java:42)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126) 
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: UI/uiskin.json
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:702)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:96)
... 7 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: UI/uiskin.json
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:77)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:700)
... 8 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing JSON on line 2 near: {
  *ERROR*com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
  white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1,
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:549)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:55)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:75)
... 9 more
```

My uiskin.json file is as follows:

```
{
  com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
  white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
  red: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 1 },
  black: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 0 }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
  default: { font: default-font }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
  default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, font: default-
font, fontColor: white },
  toggle: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, checked: default-
round-down, font: default-font, fontColor: white, downFontColor: red }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ProgressBar$ProgressBarStyle: {
  default-horizontal: { background: default-slider, knob: default-slider-
knob },
  default-vertical: { background: default-slider, knob: default-round-large 
}
}
}
```

And this is the code I use to load the uiskin.json file:

```
this.skin = new Skin();
this.skin.addRegions(MathsVsZombies.manager.get("UI/uiskin.atlas", TextureAtlas.class));
this.skin.add("default-font", MathsVsZombies.font24);
this.skin.load(Gdx.files.internal("UI/uiskin.json"));
```

**Edit: This is the newly formatted JSON file I used**

```
{
  "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color":{
    "white":{
      "a":1,
      "b":1,
      "g":1,
      "r":1
    },
    "red":{
      "a":1,
      "b":0,
      "g":0,
      "r":1
    },
    "black":{
      "a":1,
      "b":0,
      "g":0,
      "r":0
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle":{
    "default":{
      "font":"default-font"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle":{
    "default":{
      "down":"default-round-down",
      "up":"default-round",
      "font":"default-font",
      "fontColor":"white"
    },
    "toggle":{
      "down":"default-round-down",
      "up":"default-round",
      "checked":"default-round-down",
      "font":"default-font",
      "fontColor":"white",
      "downFontColor":"red"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ProgressBar$ProgressBarStyle":{
    "default-horizontal":{
      "background":"default-slider",
      "knob":"default-slider-knob"
    },
    "default-vertical":{
      "background":"default-slider",
      "knob":"default-round-large"
    }
  }
}
```

**Here is the full traceback I get when running application with new JSON file**

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: UI/uiskin.json
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:98)
at com.mathsvszombies2.game.Screens.HomeScreen.show(HomeScreen.java:66)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
at com.mathsvszombies2.game.Screens.StartScreen.render(StartScreen.java:58)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.mathsvszombies2.game.MathsVsZombies.render(MathsVsZombies.java:42)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: UI/uiskin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:702)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:96)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: UI/uiskin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:77)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:700)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing JSON 
on line 2 near: {
  *ERROR*"com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color":{
    "white":{
      "a":1,
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:549)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:55)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:75)
    ... 9 more
```

**Please help. Thanks.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the JSON file is fine and it was just Android Studio playing games. I restarted it and it runs fine now.

Comment: After reading the `uiskin.json` file [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.json), it seems that you don't need to write the class names fully and you can just write the class name such as `Color`.

Answer (score 0):

The `SerializationException` is caused by invalid input. You can read all about this exception [right here](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/SerializationException.html). In this case, the exception is telling you that there is an error in your `uiskin.json` file.

**How to fix this problem**:

- Run your `uiskin.json` code through a JSON Validator like [this one](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).
- Read the error messages that the validator gives you and re-write your JSON accordingly.

I did the above steps for you and I found that the error was caused by a couple newline characters that were invalid. It also gave errors stating that none of the strings were enclosed in quotes, however I don't think that is the main problem anymore.

After editing the json file to get rid of all the errors, the validator gave me the all clear and formatted it nicely.

So, here is the nicely formatted and valid json file.

**uiskin.json**:

```
{
   "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color":{
      "white":{
         "a":1,
         "b":1,
         "g":1,
         "r":1
      },
      "red":{
         "a":1,
         "b":0,
         "g":0,
         "r":1
      },
      "black":{
         "a":1,
         "b":0,
         "g":0,
         "r":0
      }
   },
   "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle":{
      "default":{
         "font":"default-font"
      }
   },
   "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle":{
      "default":{
         "down":"default-round-down",
         "up":"default-round",
         "font":"default-font",
         "fontColor":"white"
      },
      "toggle":{
         "down":"default-round-down",
         "up":"default-round",
         "checked":"default-round-down",
         "font":"default-font",
         "fontColor":"white",
         "downFontColor":"red"
      }
   },
   "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ProgressBar$ProgressBarStyle":{
      "default-horizontal":{
         "background":"default-slider",
         "knob":"default-slider-knob"
      },
      "default-vertical":{
         "background":"default-slider",
         "knob":"default-round-large"
      }
   }
}
```

I have not tested this code, however, I believe that this solution should cure the exception.

I hope this answer helped you and if you have any further questions please feel free to leave a comment below!

Comment: Invalid newline characters could be a problem but missing qoutes probably aren't, have a look at libgdx's own docs: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin

Comment: In that case the validator was probably being overly strict on the rules. Perhaps the newline characters are the only problem. Thanks for the information!

Comment: I actually tried this earlier before posting the question using the exact same website funnily enough but it didn't work. I tried your version of the json file too and I still get the same error. Any other ideas on what it may be? I appreciate the input though.

Comment: Post the full traceback of the error when you run my version. There seems to be an issue with one of the entries then.

Comment: Please see edit for full traceback upon running of your version

Comment: @ShahzebManjlai When asking questions in the future, please post what you have tried to solve the problem. The details you posted in the comments here belong in your original question.